# fatal: No url found for submodule path 'dist' in .gitmodules

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I am trying to deploy my app to git pages and I have status failure for GitHub pages.

When I am start "`pages build and deployment`" in Action, I have a next problems:

```
1) Build > Checkout > Fetching submodules:
  /usr/bin/git submodule sync --recursive
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 submodule update --init --force --depth=1 --recursive
  Error: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'dist' in .gitmodules
  Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

```
2)Deploy > Deploy to github pages:
Error: Error: No uploaded artifact was found! 
Please check if there are any errors at build step.
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the content of your `.gitmodules` file:

If it includes only one entry `[submodule "dist"]`, with a module path `dist`, without URL,
then delete the `.gitmodules` file entirely, add, and commit.
(Note: [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67396346/6309), check if you have a `dist` (no trailing slash) entry, and remove it if you do: `git rm --cached -- dist`).

Then try again the deployment process.

A valid `.gitmodules` entry should have both URL *and* path:

```
[submodule "dist"]
    path = dist
    url = git://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Comment: I tried following these steps and am still getting the same error. The error: `Error: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'themes/avicenna' in .gitmodules`. However, my `.gitmodules` file (in the root directory of the repo containing the submodule) contains a `[submodule "themes/avicenna/"]` entry with the correct url. I'd really appreciate any suggestions on where I'm going wrong!

Comment: @sdg Maybe a `git submodule update --init` would help Git to re-read your `.gitmodules` and initialize it accordingly?

Comment: Thanks @VonC. This helped me figure out that the submodule entry was missing a `path` entry, as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule).

Comment: @sdg Thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer to make that clearer.