# What happens during a git submodule push

Tags: git, git-submodules

I can *pull* submodule (`subby`) latest commit locally with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5828396/3357352):

```bash
$ git clone --recurse-submodules <omitted>/importer.git
$ cd importer
$ cat subby/README.md
cat: subby/README.md: No such file or directory
#
# good ! it's not supposed to exist
#
$ git submodule foreach git pull origin master
Entering 'subby'
<omitted>
Fast-forward
 README.md | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README.md
$ cat subby/README.md 
Hello oren
#
# good ! now it exists
#
```

But now I want to *push* that change

```bash
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   subby (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Closing my eyes and hoping for the best worked with:

```
$ git add subby
$ git commit -m "updating subby"
$ git push
```

But what exactly did I commit? the sub-folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have committed a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66959002/6309)** (as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)), a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309) ([documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) representing the submodule root SHA1.

That way, the `git clone --recurse-submodules`  knows *which commit* of that submodule to checkout.