# How can I see the the submodules inside of my github repository?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

Ive created one repo out of two small repos which are now submodules. In this `Master Repo`, I can change these submodules and commit them to a PR from the `Master Repo`, however in Github, I am unable to actually open the submodules in Github. They are hidden behind an unclickable file with the `submodule repo #` name and the folder icon has a little white arrow pointing right [see image]

[image]

This is the folder structure. Each submodule ofc has its own remote added pointing to the original repo that it came from.

```js
Master Repo ->
  -submodule repo 1 
  -submodule repo 2
```

How can I get github to actually show the contents of these submodules in things like pull request reviews and such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I look at my own repository [`github.com/VonC/git-cred`](https://github.com/VonC/git-cred), my submodule [`batcolors @ 83bcef4`](https://github.com/VonC/batcolors/tree/83bcef4cf8b3d79b86cb5823d59fb3fa21ccd8c6) is clickable.

It is composed of:

- an URL in the [`.gitmodules` of my parent repository](https://github.com/VonC/git-cred/blob/3d8238e136cb6026ecf676e67c4a6d05a52c7986/.gitmodules#L3).
- a [**gitlink**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73834723/6309) (SHA1 [recorded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) as a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309))

In your case, check if:

- the submodule and its exact path are declared in your own `.gitmodules` file
- if the associated URL is one GitHub can interpret.

---

> How can I get GitHub to actually show the contents of these submodules in things like pull request reviews and such?

That is not supported with a submodule approach (reference to a sub-repository).

A **[subtree approach](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree)** would:

- preserve the Git history of the smaller repository before being "integrated" into the bigger one
- show diffs during a pull request.

[image: https://wac-cdn.atlassian.com/dam/jcr:f5fcef58-5b93-4ff4-b9a1-3f721d29ead8/BeforeAfterGitSubtreeDiagram.png?cdnVersion=637]

Comment: I think the OP is trying to view the diffs of his submodule(s) *in the pull request view*. afaik it is not possible in the web GUI at the moment, but perhaps you know better

Comment: While this solution does allow me to open the submodules, it merely redirects me to the submodule's repo url upon opening. What I want is that the submodule/ smaller repo is a part of the parent repo but still maintains the git history from before the two smaller repos were merged. For example, if i deleted www.github.com/repo1 and repo2, the parent repo and its sub-repos would not be affected.

Comment: @IanSteffy "What I want is that the submodule/ smaller repo is a part of the parent repo but still maintains the git history from before the two smaller repos were merged.": that what a submodule is: its own Git history is maintained. There is no "merge".

Comment: @IanSteffy Maybe a subtree approach would be a better fit in your case? See my edited answer.

Comment: @VonC This is what I was looking for. Thanks and enjoy the bounty, bounty hunter.