# How can I add commits from submodules to main repository

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, tags, git-submodules

I have a repository with one submodule.

But I would like the commits made in the submodule to be informed in my tag used in the main repository.

Is it possible to perform this procedure?

Note: I use the Jenkins tool for build, deploy and it has a stage for creating tags.

I have been trying the commands below:

This command doesn't put the commits on tag

`git submodule update --init --recursive --remote`

This command return the message: Entering 'SUBMODULE/FOLDER'

`git submodule foreach --recursive 'git fetch --tags --force'`

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do and create commits in your submodule.

The changed state (meaning the fact the submodule checked out in your main repository is at a different root tree SHA1) will be detected.

That is a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73834723/6309)**, a SHA1 [recorded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) as a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309).

In said main project, add and commit the your new submodule state (your gitlink special entry).

Answer (score 0):

You've probably noticed in "git status" that sometimes the submodules read as modified.

[image: git status output showing a changed submodule]

That's because the commit that was checked out inside that submodule directory has changed.

When you `git add path/to/submodule` and `git commit` a change to a submodule in the parent project, it records the hash that submodule is checked out to. If you then commit that change, it commits the "submodule state".

### Don't use `submodule update` with `--remote`!

Use `git submodule update --init --recursive` instead (in the parent project). This will checkout all submodules to the state saved in the parent project's commit.

Using `--remote` destroys any guarantee of submodule state.