# react project changes to a subProject

Tags: reactjs, github

I have a project which contains 3 class projects, an API and React project.

I tried to push it to GitHub, the React project turns to a subproject in the project (can not click on it or open it).
Furthermore, I tried to clone the repo, but I get that the project file cannot be found:

[image: not found]

[image: white arrow]

I tried to add it as a subModule, but I am getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The [white arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057615/6309) on that `client-pro` folder means it is probably a nested Git repository.

Removing and adding that repository as a submodule is a good option, provided you push first the `client-pro` repository.

Once it is pushed, make sure you add `client-pro` (no trailing slash), commit and push. This time, you should see a commit, indicating an actual submodule accessible through its [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73834723/6309).