# How can I use git submodules in a project

Tags: git

When I am working with git submodules, in the parent repo I don't see the changes I have made in the submodule, I can only see the previous commit id. Can anyone please help me with the process

I have created submodules. this is the folder structure--

parent
--submodule1
--submodule2
--pipeline script

I can't see the changes made in the submodules from the parent folder.

Expectation: I will be able to see the changes made in each submodule from the parent folder.

Comment: What does it mean "*be able to see the changes made in each submodule*"? Do you mean `git diff --submodule` ?

Comment: You should add the commands that you’ve tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about what you see on the remote side (like a GitHub repository on `github.com`), then yes, you would see only the previous commit, with a [white arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057615/6309) to reference the [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73834723/6309) (the reference to said previous commit).

Locally, when you are modifying a submodule content, adding and pushing to the submodule remote repository, you *also* need to go back to your parent local repository, add, commit and push from there: that will record the new gitlink (the new SHA1 of your submodule root tree), and push it: you would see the last submodule commit there, but still as a reference.