# Running "git rm --cached" removes files from the .git folder?

Tags: git, git-rm

I'm having trouble understanding what does `git rm --cached` do.

For example, I have a beagle_pft_test repo and a list of submodules inside "components folder". doing `git rm --cached` would delete it form the .git folder?:

[image]

Because when I type the following:

```
git rm --cached components/ChrgTmptrSen
```

And I get:

```
rm 'components/ChrgTmptrSen'
```

But I still see the component in the `.git` folder:

[image]

I'm not sure where did it remove it from? If I still see it in the .git folder, the .gitsubmodules file and the physical component in my local working directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste)

Comment: If you `git rm file`, commit, then check out the previous commit, do you expect `file` to be there?

Comment: Gaston, from the link it says that running `git rm --cached` deletes it from the index in the  `.git` folder, but when I run it I still see it. I took a screenshot of it.

Comment: @tadm123: "the index" is a part inside git storage, git lingo for files on disk is "the worktree". The `--cached` in `git rm --cached` is precisely about telling git to stop tracking these files (remove them from the index), but *leave them on disk* (leve them in the worktree) -- you will still see them in the explorer.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in "[How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309)", you would need [`git submodule deinit -f -- a/submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-deinit-f--force--all--ltpathgt82308203) to unregister the given submodules, i.e. remove the whole `submodule.$name` section from `.git/config` folder. Plus a `rm -rf .git/modules/a/submodule` for cleanup.

The `git rm --cached a/submodule` is only needed if you still want the submodule files to still be visible on your disk, while the [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73834723/6309) (special entry in the index) is removed from Git.

Comment: Is this special entry in the index on the hidden `.git` folder on the repository? If so that's strange because when I type `git rm --cached a/submodule` with the path that I want to erase, I still see it on that `.git` folder as if nothing was deleted

Comment: @tadm123 No, the special entry is just the sha1 of the submodule, and has nothing to do with a .git.